# How to mirror my source code that is in SVN repository with git

Tags: git, svn

How to mirror my source code that is in SVN repository with git.

My firm keeps all its source code in SVN.  I what to checkout all the code from the svn repository and then import it into a git repo on the internet so I can go home and get everything out of the git repo.  I am never going to be making code changes at home so this is going to be a one-way mirror.. I just want to keep mirroring the code I have at work in my git  repo and then downloading it at home?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you explored using git-svn? It allows you to operate between a git and svn repository. 
Here's a link: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing the following steps:

```
cd ~/tmp/svn-mirror/
git svn clone http://svn/java mirror.git

cd ~/tmp/svn-mirror/mirror.git/
git remote add origin git@git.xxxx.com:MIRROR.git
git push origin master

Then Script
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/tmp/svn-mirror/mirror.git/
git svn rebase
git push origin master
```